# Selecting the first instance of a html class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some trouble with jQuery overwriting the elements of a particular parent class. For instance, I have two classes that have the same name but I am looking only to use the first instance for a particular purpose and then the others for something else, but the data inside keeps being overwritten by the next function I am using. I think I know why it is doing it, I'm just unsure of how to fix it so it doesn't.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
function buildFriendStatus() {
    $.getJSON('/members/feed/get-friend-status', function(data) {
        var notFirstElement = $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin:not(first)')

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var element = notFirstElement.eq(i);

            element.find('h4').html(data[i].username);
            element.find('p').html(data[i].status);
            element.find('img').attr('src', data[i].images);
        });
    }).fail(function(response) {
        console.log(response.fail);
    }); 
}


function buildSelfStatus() {
    $.getJSON('/members/feed/list-own-status', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin:first').find('h4').html(data[i].username);
            $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin:first').find('p').html(data[i].status);
            $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin:first').find('img').attr('src', data[i].images);
        });
    }).fail(function(response) {
        console.log(response.fail);
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    buildFriendStatus();
}, 1000);
```

and then the html/calling of the functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        buildSelfStatus();
        buildFriendStatus();
</script>

<!-- always have this first (sticky) for the user status -->
<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin">
    <h4></h4>

    <p></p>

    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin: 0 -16px;">
        <div class="w3-half">
            <img src="" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" alt="<?php echo $this->identity() . "'s image"; ?>" class="w3-margin-bottom w3-round w3-border">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin">
    <h4></h4>

    <p></p>

    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin: 0 -16px">
        <div class="w3-half">
            <img src="" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" alt="<?php echo "Image"; ?>" class="w3-margin-bottom w3-round w3-border">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom">
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comment
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

Updated screenshot (shows the first image but not the other result(s) now)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Oh, on another note, is there a way to use jQuery to put data inside the class but have the class be shown more than once without overwriting the data previously added but only have one `<div>` element with the class name? Sort of like the screenshot attached but just not overwriting each class the same time. Just curious as I couldn't find anything regarding this. I guess I mean build the div element and it's child elements dynamically based on the results retrieved via `$.getJSON`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here, or what the screenshot is supposed to demonstrate,  but jquery selectors can be treated as an array: `$(foo)[0]` returns the first matching element.

Comment: I don't want the same data to shown more than once in the class. It is overwriting it (I want the first to be separate) but use the same class.

Comment: the answer that was provided fixed the problem with the first one but the second one won't show any data and there is no errors in the console. Not sure why it was deleted or why my question got downvoted.

Comment: There's some terminology confusion here which is making it difficult to tell what you're asking.  Classes are labels attached to DOM elements.  Classes don't contain data; it's not possible to have two different classes with the same name; I don't know what you mean by "have the class be shown more than once" or "overwriting the class".  Can you please try to boil this down to a more coherent question?  One good place to start would be to reduce your example code to just what's needed to demonstrate whatever the problem is, and to be more explicit about what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I know it's not. I'm trying to get the first instance of the class to show particular data while the others show other data.

Comment: And then build elements with the css class and the child elements attached dynamically based on the results returned in buildFriendStatus function. I don't know how I can better explain it.. 

Comment: change `element.find('h4').html(data[i].username);` to `element.find('h4').html(i);` i want to know the result

Comment: @plonknimbuzz it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".getfirst").click(function(){
 alert($(".testdiv").first().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testdiv">
33
</div>
<div class="testdiv">
44
</div>
<div class="testdiv">
55
</div>
<div class="testdiv">
66
</div>
<div class="getfirst" style="width:150px; height:50px; background-color:red;">
  get me!!
</div>
```

Why dont you use .first() of jQuery?

For example lets say you have 4 divs with same class but you want to get the text of the first div element with the specific class name:

```
<div class="testdiv">33</div>
<div class="testdiv">44</div>
<div class="testdiv">55</div>
<div class="testdiv">66</div>

<div class="getfirst" style="width:150px; height:50px; background-color:red;">
  get me!!
</div>


$(".getfirst").click(function(){
    alert($(".testdiv").first().text());
});
```

Comment: because i want the same class style for all of them

Comment: Did you run my code snippet? Does that do what you need?

Comment: it isn't what I need, I know it will work but I want to use the same class for each thing so i can keep the style. The first one works, its the other one that follows that is not working (see `buildFriendStatus`). Plus I am trying to figure out how to dynamically add each section with the results returned from `$.getJSON`

Answer (score -1):

just added another class to the first element.